# How I create a singleton class on flask that flush on request's end

Tags: python, flask, singleton

I was trying to create a singleton class on flask application but in new requests it doesn't flush. Someone knows how I create a singleton that flush on each request?

```
class YoutubeService():
    _instance = None
    _infos = {}

    def __init__(self):
        raise Exception('')

    @classmethod
    def get_info(cls, id):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = cls.__new__(cls)
        self = cls
        if id not in self._infos:
            self._infos[id] = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos', params={
                'part': ['id'],
                'id': id,
                'key': os.getenv('GOOGLE_API_KEY')
            }).json()['items'][0]
        return self._infos[id]
```

Comment: Does your flask app use this `YoutubeService`? Seeing how it is being used would help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution

I put the _infos on flask context and create a tear_down

```
from flask import g
import requests
import os


def get_youtube_info(youtube_id):
    if 'youtube_context' not in g:
        g.youtube_context = {}
    context = g.youtube_context
    if id not in context:
        context[youtube_id] =     requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos', params={
            'part': ['id', 'snippet'],
            'id': youtube_id,
            'key': os.getenv('GOOGLE_API_KEY')
        }).json()['items'][0]
    return context[youtube_id]


def _tear_down():
    if 'youtube_context' in g:
        delattr(g, 'youtube_context')
```

But i do not know if this is appropriate